# Stack overflow solution with O(n) runtime

Tags: performance

I have a problem related to runtime for push and pop in a stack.

Here, I implemented a stack using array.

I want to avoid overflow in the stack when I insert a new element to a full stack, so when the stack is full I do the following (Pseudo-Code):

(I consider a stack as an array)

1. Generate a new array with the size of double of the origin array.
2. Copy all the elements in the origin stack to the new array in the same order.

Now, I know that for a single push operation to the stack with the size of n the action executes in the worst case in O(n).

I want to show that the runtime of n pushes to an empty stack in the worst case is also O(n).

Also how can I update this algorithm that for every push the operation will execute in a constant runtime in the worst case?

Comment: If you are aware of how std::vector works in c++ its somewhat like this only. It uses arrays internally of some fixed size. When this size is reached it makes a vector of size double the original size and then copies all the elements to this array. This is said to be in amortized constant time O(1). Amortized here is the key word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amortized constant-time is often just as good in practice if not better than constant-time alternatives.

> 1. Generate a new array with the size of double of the origin array.
> 2. Copy all the elements in the origin stack to the new array in the same order.

This is actually a very decent and respectable solution for a stack implementation because it has good locality of reference and the cost of reallocating and copying is amortized to the point of being almost negligible. Most generalized solutions to "growable arrays" like `ArrayList` in Java or `std::vector` in C++ rely on this type of solution, though they might not exactly double in size (lots of `std::vector` implementations increase their size by something closer to 1.5 than 2.0).

One of the reasons this is much better than it sounds is because our hardware is super fast at copying bits and bytes sequentially. After all, we often rely on millions of pixels being blitted many times a second in our daily software. That's a copying operation from one image to another (or frame buffer). If the data is contiguous and just sequentially processed, our hardware can do it very quickly.

> Also how can I update this algorithm that for every push the operation
>   will execute in a constant runtime in the worst case?

I have come up with stack solutions in C++ that are ever-so-slightly faster than `std::vector` for pushing and popping a hundred million elements and meet your requirements, but only for pushing and popping in a LIFO pattern. We're talking about something like 0.22 secs for vector as opposed to 0.19 secs for my stack. That relies on just allocating blocks like this:

[image]

... of course typically with more than 5 elements worth of data per block! (I just didn't want to draw an epic diagram). There each block stores an array of contiguous data but when it fills up, it links to a next block. The blocks are linked (storing a previous link only) but each one might store, say, 512 bytes worth of data with 64-byte alignment. That allows constant-time pushes and pops without the need to reallocate/copy. When a block fills up, it just links a new block to the previous block and starts filling that up. When you pop, you just pop until the block becomes empty and then once it's empty, you traverse its previous link to get to the previous block before it and start popping from that (you can also free the now-empty block at this point).

Here's your basic pseudo-C++ example of the data structure:

```
template <class T>
struct UnrolledNode
{
    // Points to the previous block. We use this to get
    // back to a former block when this one becomes empty.
    UnrolledNode* prev;

    // Stores the number of elements in the block. If
    // this becomes full with, say, 256 elements, we
    // allocate a new block and link it to this one.
    // If this reaches zero, we deallocate this block
    // and begin popping from the previous block.
    size_t num;

    // Array of the elements. This has a fixed capacity,
    // say 256 elements, though determined at runtime
    // based on sizeof(T). The structure is a VLS to
    // allow node and data to be allocated together.
    T data[];
};

template <class T>
struct UnrolledStack
{
     // Stores the tail end of the list (the last
     // block we're going to be using to push to and
     // pop from).
     UnrolledNode<T>* tail;
};
```

That said, I actually recommend your solution instead for performance since mine barely has a performance edge over the simple reallocate and copy solutions and yours would have a slight edge when it comes to traversal since it can just traverse the array in a straightforward sequential fashion (as well as straightforward random-access if you need it). I didn't actually implement mine for performance reasons. I implemented it to prevent pointers from being invalidated when you push things to the container (the actual thing is a memory allocator in C) and, again, in spite of achieving true constant-time push backs and pop backs, it's still barely any faster than the amortized constant-time solution involving reallocation and memory copying.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the comprehensive answer and clarification. But I want to know if there is any solution that handle only two stacks at a time-with the size of n and the size of 2n and the action pop and push will still be in a constant time?

Comment: Cheers and Happy New Year!

Comment: `But I want to know if there is any solution that handle only two stacks at a time-with the size of n and the size of 2n and the action pop and push will still be in a constant time?` My bad, I didn't notice your edit until just now... If it's two stacks using the above solution, then it'd still be two iterations to push and pop and still constant-time. Naturally pushing and popping to n-stacks would inevitably be linear time, since we'd have to inevitably mutate `n` stacks. But two stacks would still be a constant with `k=2`.